# accumarray function not working in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an 2D array like the one shown below.

```
35046,  0.17    
1963,   0.34    
1135,   0.51    
405,    0.68    
99, 0.85    
1,  0.85    
15, 1.02    
2,  1.02
```

I tried using accumarray function in matlab on this data to get the results like this below.

```
35046,  0.17    
1963,   0.34    
1135,   0.51    
405,    0.68    
100,    0.85    
17, 1.02
```

The following is the code snippet for the same.

```
[num_dist, txt_dist]=xlsread(fname);
num_dist_final(:,1) = accumarray(num_dist(:,2),num_dist(:,1));
num_dist_final(:,2) = unique(num_dist(:,2));
```

But accumarray throws an error 'Error using accumarray: First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts.'.

Is there way where I can use accumarray for float subscripts like the one in this problem?

Any other alternate methods are also welcome.

Comment: Since this question is purely about implementation, it is more on topic for stackoverflow and you would have gotten a faster answer there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dan! But there is a question ban which has been put there for my account and hence had to ask it here due to lack of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the third output of [`unique`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to convert your floats to a format suitable for `accumarray`:

```
[C,~,ib] = unique(num_dist(:,2))
num_dist_final(:,1) = accumarray(ib,num_dist(:,1))
num_dist_final(:,2) = C
```